# Android webview I can't show

Tags: android, webview

https://mobilogr.uludag.edu.tr/Login.aspx

I can't open this website in Android webview

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true); 
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uygulama Yükleniyor",
            "...yükleniyor...");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
```

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://mobilogr.uludag.edu.tr/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: cilgin : Please post Error stack trace here from your Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your android Android Manifest for the Internet Permission as shown below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: ow i dont have a problem about permissions

Answer (score 0):

Does your application have the permission to go on the internet?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

also, you want to go to [this](https://mobilogr.uludag.edu.tr/Login.aspx) website,
but your url in your script goes to another?

Comment: no no i have problem about https://mobilogr.uludag.edu.tr/Login.aspx  this website ,

Comment: i can open other websites but i cant open this(https://mobilogr.uludag.edu.tr/Login.aspx )

Comment: when you enter that website in your mobile browser, does the website work?

Comment: Oke, try this site in your url, instead of the one you are using now: http://portal.saveetha.com/deptweb/home/Login.aspx

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the .aspx

Comment: I guess  theproblem is certificate

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue. 
The easiest way is to debug and see, the page may have a broken javascript.
You need to remote debug which give you clear error in console.

Try this : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with the certificate.

if your ssl Certificate expired or not trusted,webview will refuse to load the webpage.
To avoid this ,you should override onReceivedSslError method like this:

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
          // super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
          // ignore ssl error
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
```

i try this,everything is OK.